# How to wake a sleeping laptop

Tags: windows-7, laptop, sleep, power-management

I have an old compaq pressario CQ61 that's getting a bit old and I'm trying to convert to a media server. I want to put it by the TV and leave it mostly alone, and manage remotely (via RealVNC).

Now my main challenge is getting it to wakeup. I've tried Wake on LAN and USB devices, and primarily it seems the BIOS doesn't allow it.

I tried 'pressing any key' with the lid closed using a long stick, and this doesn't work either! it appears the laptop detects the lid is closed somehow, and prevents the keyboard from waking it. If the lid is closed, and I open it, the laptop comes out of standby.

Does anyone know how I can wake the laptop with the keyboard, even if the lid is closed?

**Edit**: Just to restate. The problem is not relating to the laptop *going to sleep* when the lid is closed. The problem is that I cannot *WAKE* it when it is closed. My power settings are already set to Do Nothing on lid close.

Comment: If you cant get it to wake up, then the alternative would be to get it to go to sleep when you know everyone has gone to bed (say 1am) and then wake up when you know people will want to watch TV (say 7am). That'll give you 6 hours of reduced power consumption. On my Windows 7 based HTPC I also find a daily reboot (after it has woken up) helps ensure that odd glitches don't start to occur.

Comment: Thanks Richard, I had considered something like that, as 'wake on timer' is something I've not tried yet. If I can't do it properly, that'll be my fallback

Answer (score 3):

First thing to deal with would be the lid closing. On Windows 7 you can go into:

`Control Panel > All Control Panel Items > Power Options > System Settings`

Simply set it to do nothing when you close the lid.

You need to bear in mind a couple things. Wake on LAN is disabled by default on laptops, some systems can't accept the package type and it does not work through wireless. Since I don't know what BIOS you are using I suggest you have a look around your BIOS and see if you can accept the right packages.

If you need more help you can post your BIOS spec or check out Microsoft guide  [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617165%28WS.10%29.aspx)

UPDATE: Give this a try for accepting Wake on LAN

If you can't find the settings in your BIOS try going into:

Device Manager > Network Adapter > Right Click Properties > Advanced

Look for Wake from Shutdown or Wake on Magic Packet. Ensure this is enabled.

Then under the Power Management tab ensure "Allow this device to wake the computer" is enabled.

Comment: Updated question. I already have that setting applied, and it doesn't appear to have anything to do with waking the laptop - only sleeping it. My BIOS didn't WoLAN support it out of the box, but I did flash it with a custom BIOS that showed a Wake on PME option. However after all that, I've had issues with he wired connection - so that's another problem :(

Comment: Put your computer to sleep and have a look at the ethernet LEDs. Are they still blinking? If not you probably can't accept ethernet packets when the system is asleep - I will edit my answer with another method should you wish to try it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that having the machine always on is an option (and therefore not needing to wake it from sleep), then don't allow the machine to turn off or sleep when the lid is shut -there is often a setting what power option to choose when the lid is down (you may even find an option which does suffice).

> Open Power Options by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start
>   button, clicking Control Panel, clicking System and Security, and then
>   clicking Power Options.
>
> On the Select a power plan page, click Choose what closing the lid
>   does.
>
> On the Define power buttons and turn on password protection page, next
>   to When I close the lid, choose what you want your laptop to do, both
>   for when it's running on battery and when it's plugged in.

[Source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows7/change-what-happens-when-you-close-your-laptop)

Comment: Always on is an option, but due to the low usage I'll make of it I DO want it to sleep  - but then to be able to wake it up without opening the lid